# Anchor link with space in it

Tags: jquery, navigation, scrollto

I´ve got this script:

### JS

```
$("#content div.nav").each(function() {
   $(".navi ul").append('<li><a href="#'+ $(this).attr("id") + '">' + $(this).attr("id") + '</a></li>');
});
```

It generates out of ID´s a navigation, but sometimes I´ve got a ID with a space for example "Agen da" and with such an anker the script doesnt scroll, can you help me with that?

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/14/

Comment: `id` should not have space at first place.

Comment: Do you just want to kill the spaces or make it work with the spaces?

Comment: I know that ID´s are not suppost to have spaces but this way it is easier to work with for the editors.

I would like to get it to work with the spaces.

Comment: Use data attributes instead of having invalid html...

Comment: What do you mean with "data attributes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make it work with spaces :)

Create your divs like this:

```
<div title="Location 3" id="Location3" class="nav">
```

Remove the spaces in your id's then add `title` attribute which can have spaces.

Then have your script like this:

```
$("#content div.nav").each(function() {
    $(".navi ul").append('<li><a href="#'+ $(this).attr("id") + '">' + $(this).attr("title") + '</a></li>');
});
```

Notice that I replaced the second `id` with `title`

Check the demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/15/)

Hope it helps

Comment: It would help, but the problem is, that i dont have the element "title" in my cms.

Comment: Is there another attribute you can use? Then you can replace title with that attribute then make the changes accordingly

Comment: No, I´ve got only the option "ID" and "class"

Comment: Is it possible to create the title attribute for every div in "content" with the class"nav"? And get the value from "ID"?

Comment: Does it give you an error when you add title and run it?

Comment: I changed the code that jquery creates the "title", but how does the "title" gets the value of the "ID"?
http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/17/

Comment: But what you've done now gives all the items the same title. Check my updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/18/). Its a bit dirty but it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51413/discussion-between-lydia-maier-and-dumisani)

Answer (score 0):

HTML element ID's can not have spaces.